# Time image is visible on display Android

Tags: android, listview, imageview, android-arrayadapter

In my activity I have a listview with a custom adapter that extends an ArrayAdapter.
Now my listview is like the home page of Instagram or Facebook. There are a lot of pictures that have been posted by users. Each listview item height is approximately the height of the screen. What I want to do is to count for how many milliseconds a user watch an image. This means for how much the image is displayed on the screen.

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: use a timertask and when user scrolls restart it.

Comment: But what if he scrolls just a little bit and the image is still fully visible?

Comment: check for getItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Timer  class to count the time.

- Start the timer from the beginning.
- check the currently visible item using **getFirstVisiblePosition()** in each scroll using **OnScrollListener**.
- if the position is changed, increment the view time of appropriate item and reset the timer.
- When items are partially visible, you can find the visible portions of both items using **listItem.getTop()** and **listItem.getBottom()** and assume that the user is viewing item with higher visible portion right now. (You said "Each listview item height is approximally the height of the screen". So, there must be maximum of two items at a time)

*Note: when checking the view time of an item, don't forget to add the value from the timer if it is the current item.*

Comment: But if i'm scrolling down it can happen that the firstVisible image is almost not visible, and the second image is almost fully visible, so technically you are watching the secon one not the first one.